# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. with getDocs()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I tried reading the first couple of answers but none seem to have the same rule with the one I currently have my hands on.

When I try to call the getDocs() function (using react)

```
let userInfo = await getDoc(doc(db, chargerInfo.userRef));
```

I seem to be getting the error `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`
what can I do to not get this error? Below is the rule that I have

````
match /devices/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
        allow update: if request.auth != null;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Are you sure the user is logged in before the query? Can you try logging user info to ensure that? Also where is `"db"` defined?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I am getting db from `const db = getFirestore();` (getFirestore() is imported from firebase/firestore)

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a single document (because your question says `getDocs()`)? In that case can you log `chargerInfo.userRef` and share a screenshot of it's value?

Comment: @Dharmaraj chargerInfo.userRef logs devices/TEST-0031. Also auth.currentUser.uid logs the correct user id

Comment: Where is `chargerInfo.userRef` coming from? Is it a Document Reference type field? If yes then you can directly use `getDoc(chargerInfo.userRef)`. Also have you tried logging user UID before the query just to ensure the user is logged in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change to:

```
 ...
 allow read: if true;
 allow update: if true;
 ...
```

Comment: Sadly, I cannot do this because they want it to have those rules

Comment: If you want `request.auth` to not be null, then you'll need to use Firebase Authentication to authenticate users.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It ended up being their rules on firebase. Will accept this answer as it is the only way for me to test my code right now.

Answer (score 0):

In your app inside cloud firestore, go to rules and replace 'allow read and write...etc." sentence with the following line:

allow read, write: if request.time > timestamp.date(2020, 9, 10);